# new Typescript file - How to exclude javascript file and compilation by default

Tags: typescript

I have a custom build process set up that compiles single-class-per-file TypeScript files into several modules.

I have no need for the TypeScriptCompile build action nor the accompanying javascript files that are attached to the TypeScript file by default.

Is there anyway to remove both by default? As in a new Typescript file should not create any javascript files and the build action shoudl be None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a new project, using the latest version of TypeScript and WebEssentials, the javascript files are not created on save OR compile, by default. Check your csproj or vbproj file for anything related to typescript compilation and simply remove it.

You actually haven't specified what your development environment looks like, so I should point out that my answer is based on using VS 2012.